# Problemas Sellar CFDI 3.3 con OpenSSL

Tags: openssl

estoy cambiando de `SHA-1` a `SHA-256` para la versión 3.3 de CFDI. Utilizo OpenSSL para generar la llave y firmar la cadena original pero no consigo que pasen las validaciones, si genera un sello pero lo valido con varios sitios web y no pasa. Estos son los las instrucciones del OpenSSL a ver si alguien puede ayudarme ...

> openssl pkcs8 -inform DER -in Certificado.key -passin pass:Password
>   -out Certificado.key.pem
>
> openssl dgst -sha256 -sign Certificado.key.pem  CadenaOriginal.txt |
>   openssl enc -base64 -A > Sello256.txt

Comment: Haz podido resolver el problema?

Answer (score 0):

Ese problema es muy común, te enlisto algunas soluciones que me han funcionado. Verifica que:

1. El archivo .key corresponde con el .cer del CFDI que intentas validar
2. La contraseña que estás utilizando para generar el archivo .pem es la correcta
3. Que la cadena original se generó de manera correcta. Recuerda que si tu CFDI tiene complementos, la cadena original resultante es distinta.

Espero esto resuelva tu problema
Saludos.